# Select DataFrame rows where columns are greater than values in a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of values,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5*4).reshape(5,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
         a        b        c        d 
0 0.346137 0.537688 0.984077 0.809581
1 0.644753 0.363966 0.617507 0.114848
2 0.495147 0.014281 0.780733 0.579303
3 0.393447 0.108278 0.255716 0.318466
4 0.718629 0.789863 0.217532 0.891606
```

and a series of maximums.

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(4),index=['a','b','c','d'])

a    0.005678
b    0.419059
c    0.511721
d    0.322693
```

I am trying to identify all rows in df1 where the value in the columns of df1 is larger than the corresponding value in s.

I have a way to do do this one column at a time, but would like to do it all at once.

```
df1[df1.a > s.a].index,df1[df1.b > s.b].index,df1[df1.c > s.c].index,df1[df1.d > s.d].index

(Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([0, 4], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([0, 2, 4], dtype='int64'))
```

in the end, I would like the result to be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
r,c = np.where((df1 > s).T)
out = np.split(df1.index[c], np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1 )
```

Sample run -

```
In [141]: df1
Out[141]: 
          a         b         c         d
0  0.346137  0.537688  0.984077  0.809581
1  0.644753  0.363966  0.617507  0.114848
2  0.495147  0.014281  0.780733  0.579303
3  0.393447  0.108278  0.255716  0.318466
4  0.718629  0.789863  0.217532  0.891606

In [142]: s
Out[142]: 
a    0.005678
b    0.419059
c    0.511721
d    0.322693
dtype: float64

In [143]: r,c = np.where((df1 > s).T)

In [144]: np.split(df1.index[c], np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1 )
Out[144]: 
[Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([0, 4], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([0, 2, 4], dtype='int64')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found

```
df1.loc[(df1 > s).any(axis=1) == True].index.tolist()
```

to work correctly and is concise.

Comment: That doesn't give you the intended result. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it gives me on list of all the rows in the dataframe of all columns that have values greater than their respective maximum.

Comment: Ah, I think Divakar and I mistook what you wanted seeing that last o/p of yours. I thought you wanted us to replicate it column per column basis. Never mind, but next time be very clear while asking questions.